# Django Q Filtered Results in Separate DIV

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a simple Django model and Q lookup and everything works as expected, but I'd like the filtered results to display in a separate DIV while keeping the original query list unfiltered as annotated in the attached image.  Below is my code, an annotated screenshot and a link to the page on a dev server.  Any instruction would be great.  Thank you.

**View**

```
def plaque_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Plaque.objects.active().order_by("first_name")
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Plaque.objects.all().order_by("first_name")

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(first_name__contains=query) |
            Q(last_name__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8)  # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "queryset_list": queryset_list,
        "title": "Locate a Veteran",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
    }
    return render(request, "plaques/plaque_list.html", context)
```

**Template**

```
...
{% for obj in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <th><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.first_name }}</a></th>
    <th><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.last_name }}</a></th>
    <th>{{ obj.branch }}</th>
    <th>{{ obj.rank }}</th>
    <th>{{ obj.wall|upper }}</th>
    <th>{{ obj.direction|title }}</th>
    <th>{{ obj.row }}</th>
    <th>{{ obj.plaque_num }}</th>
  </tr>
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

**Dev Server Link**
http://www.new.soledadmemorial.com/plaques/

Comment: why not create a separate qs to filtered results and pass them to the template context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on devxplorer’s suggestion, just add a second queryset to your context dictionary and use that to render your special `div`.

```
def plaque_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Plaque.objects.active().order_by("first_name")
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Plaque.objects.all().order_by("first_name")

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    filtered_results = None
    if query:
        filtered_results = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(first_name__contains=query) |
            Q(last_name__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8)  # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "queryset_list": queryset_list,
        'filtered_results': filtered_results,
        "title": "Locate a Veteran",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
    }
    return render(request, "plaques/plaque_list.html", context)
```

And then you can loop over `filtered_results` however you would like in that special div.